# Display issues with Intel NUC6i5SYH and MST hub

Tags: windows-10, displayport, mst, intel-nuc

Recently got a new [Intel NUC6i5SYH](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/nuc/nuc-kit-nuc6i5syh.html). For my display setup I have 2 x Dell ST2220M monitors, which have been working fine for years on 2 x DVI > DVI leads fed from an 8800GT. When I got the new NUC I also got a [StarTech MiniDP MST Hub](http://www.amazon.co.uk/StarTech-DisplayPort-Multi-Stream-Transport/dp/B00XXPYOJW/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8) and [2 x new DP > DVI leads](http://www.amazon.co.uk/UGREEN-Displayport-Connecting-Projectors-Displays/dp/B015IGOK9M?ie=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00). When I connected everything and fired the PC up I got nothing on the displays, apart from an error (produced by the monitor itself):

> MESSAGE The current input timing is not supported by the monitor
>   display. Please change your input timing to 1920x1080@60Hz or any
>   other monitor listed timing as per the monitor specifications.

I have managed to get into Windows by using 1 x HDMI > DVI cable using the HDMI out on the NUC. I have checked all the settings and all outputs should be outputting at the above settings (1920x1080@60Hz), but I still get the error message on the display still connected to the hub.

So far I have;

- Tested the two new leads individually on my laptop, both of which are fine
- Tried powering the hub from a USB mains charger (designed to be powered from a PC usb output)
- Setting monitor resolutions to 800x600
- Pressed the small reset/calibration button on the hub - both screen flick off and on and back to how I started - with the error message
- Downloaded and installed latest display drivers from Intel
- Checked the BIOS to make sure the port is set to output

Just to clarify, I seem to be getting no output (not a supported output anyways) from the MST hub at all. At the moment I have one monitor connected to the hub, which is connected to the mini-DP - not working, and the second monitor connected to the HDMI out - working.

Another note; the PC seems to be detecting the monitor, as my mouse continues off the edge of the screen, and I can choose to clone screens or extend, but I am still either getting the error message on the monitor or just a black screen (in this scenario, the LED on the monitor is white, which is it's "OK" colour, as opposed to orange when it has no signal from any device).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my Surface Pro 3, when connected to a docking station, using the same StarTech MiniDP splitter.  What eventually fixed my issue was this:

1. Download video drivers from Intel
2. Manually install the drivers (not using the .exe installer, but going through Device manager and using the option to Update Driver > install drivers manually > let me pick from a list... > Have Disk... > then point to the folder with the downloaded/unzipped drivers)
3. Use the Intel Graphics Control Panel > Display > Multiple Displays to identify and configure the display arrangement.

Known issues:

- Windows 10 updated itself at some point and "updated" my working Intel video driver with one that no longer worked.  I had to repeat the process to get my setup working again.
- Sometimes, when docking and undocking my device (disconnecting and reconnecting the displays)  I still have to repeat step 3 above to make the displays recognize.

Comment: Cheers, I'll give it a try

Comment: Unfortunately, same result :(

Comment: I have also tried all previous (including BETA) drivers from Intel and none of them solve the issue.